# Compare value with two clumns values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On my google sheets i've a **F** value who is **14080** and I would like to know if the value is included in the figures in two columns if yes print the value who is in the third columns **D**.

[image: Google sheet]

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F107,B105:D111,3,0),VLOOKUP(F107,C105:D111,2,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(F107, {B105:B, D105:D; C105:D}, 2, ))
```